# Wpf frame navigation and memory release

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-management

I'm making a WPF application that has a MainWindow with a frame and I navigate to different pages in that frame.

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Frame x:Name="Something" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" />
```

Navigation:

```
YouFrame.Navigate(PageX);
```

The problem is: as this is supposed to be an application that has to run all day, every day of the week with a lot of pages, controlling the memory usage is fundamental.

When I navigate between pages, the memory isn't released as supposed.
For example:
   If I navigate to a page with a scrollviewer with photos, I get the normal increase of memory.
However, when I navigate to other pages it's not releasing the memory that I don't need anymore. And for example, if I go back to the page with the scrollviewer with photos, I go to the same position of the scrollviewer that I was when I first left the page, which indicates that for some reason it is keeping the page alive and not releasing resources.

Of course I googled it, put KeepAlive=false in the page, cleared the BackEntrys in navigationService, tried different approaches with the  Frame, Pages and even with the MainWindow, everything that I remembered.

If anyone has a tip for me I would appreciate